# How can i fix "not logged in" error in laravel even after logging in?

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman, backend

Im making a gym app on laravel 9 as an api. The app will have a normal user and also an admin which has access to certain files that a normal user doesnt. For that i created a middleware but im facing a few problems there.

See even after i log in, when i try using a route protected by my isAdmin middleware, i get the error: Log in to gain access. This is the Login function:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $creds = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email|string|exists:users,email',
        'password' => ['required']
    ]);

    if (!Auth::attempt($creds)) {
        return response([ 'message' => 'Provided email or password is incorrect' ], 422);
    }

    /** @var \App\Models\User $user */
    $user = Auth::user();

    Auth::login($user);

    $token = $user->createToken('main')->plainTextToken;

    return response(compact('user', 'token'))->header('Authorization', 'Bearer '.$token);
}
```

and then this is the middleware

```php
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::guard('auth')->user();

        dd($user);

        if ($user->role == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        } else{
            return response(['msg'=>'You are not authorized for this route!']);
        }
    } else{
        return response(['msg'=>'Log In to gain access!']);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Im pretty sure the problem has to do with the token either not being sent or being stored properly, but i cant seem to find where the problem is. Also this is what im doing in Postman if that would help:

##### Login

[image]

##### Add Recipe (this is a route guarded by the middleware)

[image]

##### And also here are their headers respectively

[image]

[image]

Also i dont know if this is info that will help but i have to manually write the that bearer token for it to show up. (im a beginner so idk how it should be done)

Comment: You don't need `Auth::login` after `Auth::attempt`, as `attempt` will also log the user in. Remove `Auth::login`

Comment: Okay i removed it but it still didnt fix the issue